# Validation of dynamic fields in a MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My model looks like

```
public class Template
{
    Id
    Title
    List<Field> Fields
}
```

The “Field” Entity contains information like Name, Caption, Type (TextBox/Select/Radio), Options, and validation rules (Range, Required, string length).

The standard validation in MVC is based on DataAnnotations, but I wants to validate (Both client and Server Side) the form dynamically based on Field Metadata which is dynamic and configurable.

Is it possible? Any pointers?

PS. I searched for the similar questions, but not able to find a solid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar situation, this is how I handled it:

**Server Side**

When the POST happened I iterated over all the Fields values and did the Validation based on the validation rules I had on my objects. Then you can simply add ModelErrors to the Field object.

Since you push a Template object to the View you can access the Fields by name  `Fields[x].SomeProperty`. Make sure you have a `ValidationMessageFor` for `SomeProperty`

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Fields[x].SomeProperty", "The Error Message you want to show.);
```

**Client side**

Make sure your form has an Id so you can access the Validate method().
Then you iterate over all the fields and just add the validation as you please.

For all the validations rules check the validation Jquery documentation.

```
    $('#frmYourForm').validate();
        for (var i = 0; i < 'CountOfAllFields'; i++)
        {
            $('#Fields_' + i + '__Foo').rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: 'The Foo field is required'} });
            $('#Fields_' + i + '__Bar').rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: 'The Bar field is required'} });
        }
```

I hope I helped you on your way !

Ps, use FireBug to help you find the correct names of the properties and that's how you can link them with the ModelErrors in the modelstate etc.

Comment: Thanks, this will help. So on server side you are doing all the checks yourself?

Comment: Yes, on a Field I have a List of DynamicValidation objects ( Self written class). This class has an ErrorMessage, Enums.ValidationType property. and a ExtraProperty for stuff like MaxLength etc. The Enums.ValidationType has Required,Numeric etc. This way I can add a list of validations to my Fields. Then I wrote a method that would check the field against his Validations and if needed add the ErrorMessage to the ModelState.

Comment: About Server-Side approach: You said, that you "_iterated over all the Fields values and did the Validation based on the validation rules I had on my objects._"

Q: 'ModelState' is only in scope in a Controller or View, right?  So, I understand that the actual validation (aka if-checks) happened in the 'Field' object, but you must call 'ModelState.AddModelError()' in the controller.  Is this right?  

I'm trying to understand if you were able to do all validation in your business code versus your presentation layer code (ASP.NET MVC).  Thanks.