# Using dynamic object in ASP.NET MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

### Edit 1:

I have done some research and would like to simplify the question :

I would like to have a model with a dynamic object.

```
public dynamic AdditionRuntimeData;
```

this object will be populated at runtime using a database table.
I want to  decorate this object as well as property inside this object with DataAnnotations like Required , Range etc at runtime.

It looks like  the way to go ahead is to implement ICustomTypeDescriptor however even after the implementation , MVC doesnt like the dynamic  object in my model and will not even request metadata for it using the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider.CreateMetadata() method.

Is there a way to get around this problem ?

```
class Absence
{
    [Required()]
    public Guid EmpID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Start date is  manadatory")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Absence Start Date")]
    public DateTime AbsenceStart { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "End date is  manadatory")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Absence End Date")]
    public DateTime AbsenceEnd { get; set; }


    //Populate this using a helper class which reads from DB and creates a object tree at runtime.
    public dynamic AdditionRuntimeData;

}
```

Note : AdditionRuntimeData could be a object which has child objects or it could just be a simple property with value.

The answer given does not allow such depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Fields[x].SomeProperty", "The Error Message you want to show.);
```

Check the following link:

[Validation of dynamic fields in a MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228567/validation-of-dynamic-fields-in-a-mvc)

Comment: Thanks Carlos , this answers the question  partially. I have a more complex object than a List<ClassName> . the custom object I have might contain simple properties( str , int) or it may contain  complex object as well

e.g : 
AdditionRuntimeData might have a 
AdditionRuntimeData.CAR object 
which has
AdditionRuntimeData.CAR.CarMake 
AdditionRuntimeData.CAR.CarEnginePower  
property .
The CAR child object might have WHEEL obj.
I need to have a generic way of being able to assign attributes like  
REQUIRED or DataType(..Password)  to it.
Hence need to implemet it as a dynamic object.